# cannot create windows cluster file share using powershell/wmi

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, cluster-computing

The win32_clustershare does not have a Create method on win2008r2?  How does one create file shares using ideally wmi?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the `Win32_ClusterShare` class was read only, but could be mistaken.

To do it without WMI, you can use the cmdlets in the `FailoverClusters` module, but you'll probably have to install Windows Management Framework 3 or (preferably) WMF 4 on your Windows 2008 R2 machine since these cmdlets aren't available in Powershell 2.0.

With 3.0+, you should be able to use `Add-ClusterResource` and the related cmdlets.

Comment: This is not really accurate.  There are 3 methods, delete, getaccessmask and setshareinfo.  but no create... some sites on this internet list create... http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_clustershare/#create_methods.  Add-ClusterResource does not have a fileshare resource type.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: [wmiclass]'\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_clustershare' |gm |where $_.membertype -eq 'Method'}

Comment: @rismoney, I've edited to reflect my uncertainty about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the win32_clustershare.create does not work as expected and is broken.  Previously this class was absent altogether from windows as indicated here-

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971403

Apparently Using win32_share does the needful even for clusters.  I confirmed in HKLM\Cluster\Resources that the share is properly registered in the cluster.
Apparently windows is able to determine that the share upon creation is properly associated with a clustered disk.

I know I am not calling the win32_clustershare wrong, because I confirmed that the parameters are identical across the 2 wmi classes.

This is evident in inspecting both

(get-cimclass -ClassName win32_share).CimClassMethods["Create"].Parameters |fl *

(get-cimclass -ClassName win32_clustershare).CimClassMethods["Create"].Parameters |fl *

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Server 2012 R2/Windows 8.1, you can use the new and much improved SMB PowerShell modules. Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635726(v=wps.630).aspx and http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/managing-file-shares-windows-powershell